# Ansible modify global applicative variable

Tags: variables, ansible

on Ansible 2.2, I want to implement this logic:

```
---
- name "PLB1"
- hosts: localhost
- tasks:
    ... init variable/fact X ...

- name "PLB2"
- hosts: huge_group
- tasks:
    ... each run add something to variable X ...

- name "PLB3"
- hosts: localhost
- tasks
   - debug:
       msg="{{X}}"
```

---

I don't understand how to define and then modify the global variable (or fact) X
Could you help me?

Riccardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no global variables in Ansible.
Please look at your task again – do you really need them?

There is `hostvars` workaround exist:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        counter: 0

- hosts: mygroup
  gather_facts: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        counter: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].counter | int + 1 }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      delegate_facts: yes

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: counter
```

Note `serial: 1` for second Play – it is used to *reread* hostvars between task runs. If you don't use serial run, variable's value will be the same for all hosts.

Comment: Wow, I totally miss 'delegate_facts: yes'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, global variables are: config, environment variables and the command line.
From: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html